# Why does $\arctan(\frac{\tan \theta}{2}) \approx \frac{1}{2 - \theta} - \frac{1}{2 + \theta}$ for small $\theta$?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, taylor-expansion, approximation

In answering [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/783859/halving-a-tiny-angle-by-doubling-a-side-of-a-triangle/786577), I needed to show
that
$\arctan \left( \frac{\tan \theta}{2} \right) \approx \frac{\theta}{2}$
when $\theta$ was small.
So, naturally,
I computed the first few terms of the Taylor series for $\arctan \left( \frac{\tan \theta}{2} \right)$.
Sure enough,
the first three terms are $0 + \frac12 \theta + 0 \theta^2$.

But what I didn't expect was the striking pattern in the next few terms:
$$
\arctan \left( \frac{\tan \theta}{2} \right)
= \frac12 \theta
  + \frac{1}{8} \theta^3
  + \frac{1}{32} \theta^5
  + \frac{11}{1920} \theta^7 + \cdots
$$
It clearly seems to be the case that
\begin{align*}
\arctan \left( \frac{\tan \theta}{2} \right)
&\approx \sum_{n \ge 0} \left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)^{2n+1} \\
&= \frac{\theta / 2}{1 - \theta^2 / 4} \\
&= \frac{1}{2 - \theta} - \frac{1}{2 + \theta}. \\
\end{align*}
Here is a plot:

[image]

Honestly, I have no idea how to explain this, and in particular I'm having trouble assigning any meaning to $\frac{1}{2 - x}$ at all when $x$ is
an angle.

So, my question: **is there any intuitive geometric reason why this approximation works?  If not, is there any other concise reason?**

Obviously one can arrive at this result via algebraic manipulation (like I did above) but I am interested in a more intuitive explanation.

Comment: Go one more step, Neglect $ \theta^2 <<1 $ and you get there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The approximation you noticed is the [Padé approximant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pad%C3%A9_approximant) of order $(m,n) = (1,2)$ of $f(\theta) = \tan^{-1} \bigl( \frac{1}{2} \tan \theta \bigr)$.

Comment: "Geometric" in what sense, precisely?  You need to clearly explain what you mean.  You utilized series expansions as if that were a perfectly natural and intuitive thing to do, yet you don't ask for a geometric explanation for those.  A Padé approximant is simply a generalization of series expansions to rational functions.  If you want "intuitive" explanations, you have to establish what you would characterize as intuitive and what you would not.

Comment: Geometric means arising from a geometric picture.  For instance there are very straightforward proofs that $\sin x / x$ tends to $1$ or that the area of a circle is $\pi r^2$ using geometry.  And "intuitive" means you understand *why* it is, not just how to prove it.

Comment: Okay, that's fair enough.  I will leave it to others to do that.